# Is it possible to get a statistic of the most used colors on a smartphone screen?

Tags: screen, color

I would like to know for all rgb colors how much time a color is active on screen for all pixels and if it is possible to do it without the need to record the screen.

Comment: Tried [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gmikhail.colorpicker)? It claims to export colors to CSV//Explaining why you want to do this in the question by [edit]ing would help

Comment: Do you mean for an instance of time, or for a specific duration? I don't think Android stores this kind of stats. Also, each app/website may have a different color theme, so I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve?